# How can I initiate a SProc from ASP.NET, and return; and then poll a table that gets populated when the result is ready?

Tags: asp.net, t-sql

I have a Web-based page where users select a Date Range, and submit this to retrieve the relevant data as an ASCII file (.csv) - provided as a URL link.

For some cases this works but depending on the users internet connection, the age of the data requested, or the date range, the query generating the file takes from under a second to 5 minutes. After 30 seconds we time out the query from within ASP and advise the user the data must be requested via email.

In the background however the query completes, and the file is generated, but the user-link to that execution is lost so the file generation is wasted.

That I want to attempt is to have the user submit the query, and for the query to now run but release the handle and return a sequence number. Within the ASP we can then run a second-by-second check to see the status of that sequence number. After 10 seconds of no result we can pop up a user input and request their email (or give them the option to continue waiting).

If the user provides their email we would populate the table containing the sequence number, and have a trigger that automatically sends the URL to that email when the sequence completes.

Handling this as a job that loops is one way - but not what we want. The reason is most queries take a second but if we process the queries sequentially one long-running request will back up all the other short-running ones.

I have considered creating, and initiating, a job for each request but that seems to be unnecessary overhead.

The 3rd option is to handle it as we currently are, but after 10 seconds prompt the user for their email and initiate a 2nd request that now contains the email address. This however means each long-running query gets executed twice; again a waste.

So what I am wanting to do is 
1) Execute a SP, and within that SP generate the Sequence number (to return), and hand the execution off to a 2nd SP
2) Return the Sequence Number
3) Have the 2nd SP update the Sequence Number (table) when it is done
This means the ASP submits, and then polls. It can update the Sequence table with the users desired delivery method while SP-2 continues to run.

Comment: Another option: Change the query to store the results in the database, along with an auto-generated guid, and when the user submits their email, add it to that table with this guid - then you can use a trigger for update on that table and check if the csv column is updated, and you have an email, send the content to that email and delete the records. If you don't have an email, simply delete these records.

Comment: That makes sense but the problem remains as to how to release the handle back to the front-end once the query has been initiated? How I am experiencing it is SQL holds the ASP call open until the results are returned. If this takes longer than 30 seconds the front-end times out (or the user gets bored waiting and re-submits the request).